# Segue from modal view to tab bar view controller and not lose tab bar

Tags: swift, segue, uistoryboard

Hello Im trying to segue from a modal to a tab bar view controller without losing the tab bar? I know the question is short, but this is all I'm asking.

Scenario: I have a Tab Bar View Controllers, A and B. B modals to C view controller. Then I want to return to View Controller A.

Swift please :D

Comment: Are you returning to the tab bar controller from a viewController that was presented modally, or are you modally presenting a view that is contained in a tab bar controller?

Comment: yes, tab bar viewcontroller then modal to a view controller then back to another tab bar viewcontroller

Comment: back to another tab in the same viewController?

Comment: another tab, i added it to the edit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is my example of how to do this.  In my setup, I choose the *yellow ViewController* from the tab, then press *Go!* which modally presents the *white ViewController*.  Pressing *Exit* returns to the *green ViewController*.

[image: Storyboard overview]

---

To set this up, use an *unwind segue* to return to the viewController that called you.  For instance, implement this in the first ViewController of the tab (the one calling the modal segue).

```
@IBAction func backFromModal(_ segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    print("and we are back")
    // Switch to the second tab (tabs are numbered 0, 1, 2)
    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```

Then switch to another tab using `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = n` where `n` is the number of the tab you really want to go to.  To set up the unwind segue, you can either <kbd>control</kbd>-drag from a button in your modal view controller to the *exit* icon at the top of the viewController and select `backFromModal` from the pop up...

[image: drag from button to Exit]
[image]

---

**OR**

you can set up the unwind segue to be called programmatically by <kbd>control</kbd>-dragging from the *viewController* icon at the top of the modal viewController to the *exit* icon, and select `backFromModal` from the pop up.

[image]

Then, go to the *Document Outline View* and click on the *unwind segue*

[image]

and give it an *identifier* in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right (for example `"returnFromModal"`).

[image]

Then you'd call the *unwind segue* like this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "returnFromModal", sender: self)
```

Comment: perfect answer! It did exactly with what I wanted to do, I dont know "self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex" existed!

Comment: How do you pass data to the green view controller?

Comment: @Suragch, to pass data to the green view controller from the white one, it is possible to unwind directly to the green view controller and pass the data during `prepare(for:sender:)`.

Comment: Oh! I had assumed that I could only unwind directly to a parent. That's great. I'll work on that.

Comment: Yeah.  Usually it is only a parent, but you can also unwind to any of the base level VC's in a tab view controller.

Comment: I followed your advice to segue directly to the second tab and send data. It worked well. [Here is my example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751962/3681880)

Comment: Looks good @Suragch.  Question. I'm having a mental block. How do you insert links into comments and give them a nice name as you did with "Here is my example" above?  Are you manually formatting that, and could you me an example of the syntax for that?

Comment: NVM, I found the info [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757).

Comment: I wish there were some editor button shortcuts for the comments, but yes, as you discovered I just manually write out `[my text](http://example.com)`.