# unwind segue from coded button - swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, unwind-segue

Im trying to use unwind segue to go back from a controller where users have to select an option:

In the main controller, users can touch a button that direct them to a second view controller where I programmatically build up buttons (the options). when the users select one of the buttons, I want them to go back to the previous controller and pass the button data along.

I can't find a way to make the unwind segue work.

here is what I have in the second view controller:

```
// Tile touch handler function when button pressed
    func selectedMood(sender:UIButton){
        println("touching tile")

        if(self.toShow == "mood"){
            self.mood = moodAre[sender.tag - 1]
        }
        else{
            self.action = actionAre[sender.tag - 1]
        }

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("BackToPhraseSegue", sender: self)
    }

@IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        if (segue.identifier == "BackToPhraseSegue") {
            let destination = (segue.destinationViewController as! PhraseController)
            destination.mood = self.mood
            destination.action = self.action
            destination.place = self.place
        }
    }

    // Data transmit between controller
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "BackToPhraseSegue") {
            let destination = (segue.destinationViewController as! PhraseController)
            destination.mood = self.mood
            destination.action = self.action
            destination.place = self.place
        }
    }
```

I linked the controller to the exit button (selecting the `prepareForUnwind` func) in the storyboard and I gave an identifier to the unwindSegue "`BackToPhraseSegue`"

What am I missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the second part of this answer to make sure you wired up the segue correctly.

[How to wire up the exit segue so it can be called programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992088/1630618)

The function you are unwinding to needs to be in the viewController you are returning to.  Instead of `prepareForUnwind`, you need an `unwindToHere` in the previous viewController (the viewController you are returning to):

```
@IBAction func unwindToHere(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // And we are back
    let svc = segue.sourceViewController as! TheViewControllerClassYouAreReturningFrom
    // use svc to get mood, action, and place
}
```

Comment: awesome! in fact I was trying to act from the wrong controller... thanks you very much! it wasn't clear enough in what I read on the subject.