# Pass image from ViewController to ViewController child of TabBarController in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been at this problem for a few days can't crack it. Here is an overview for context.

User starts at `HomeViewController` which is a tabbed view. Tap button activates segue to `SketchViewController` which is not tabbed. User sketches an image. User taps Done button to indicate sketch is finished. Image is saved to small, hidden, `UIImageView` on `SketchViewController`. I want to pass this image to HomeViewController, where it will be used.

Here is the `SketchViewController` where the image starts:

```
class SketchViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var SketchHiddenImage: UIImageView!

@IBAction func DoneButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
//screenshot taken which results in the following
SketchHiddenImage.image = image
}

// Pass image to HomeViewController

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toTabController" {
    let tabbar: UITabBarController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        let DestViewController: HomeViewController = tabbar.viewControllers?.first as! HomeViewController

 DestViewController.sketchImage = SketchHiddenImage.image
}
}
```

Here is the HomeViewController where I want the image to end up:

```
class AskViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var HiddenTransferImage: UIImageView!

var sketchImage = UIImage!()
}
```

I have a storyboard "`show`" segue from `SketchViewController` to `TabViewController` with identity "`toTabController`".

I have seen all of the other similar posts, but this situation has a few complications for example the `TabBarController` and no amount of amalgamation and manipulation of those other posts has helped me fix this so far. Anyways, thank you for the guidance.

Comment: A note for future people referencing this, AskViewController = HomeViewController, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use a normal segue to return to your `HomeViewController` because it creates a new view controller.  Instead, you want to use an *unwind segue*.

Look at this question for how to set up an unwind segue:

[How to set up unwind segue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30991551/1630618)

You can use `prepareForSegue` with an unwind segue.  The destination view controller will be the view controller that you are returning to (that is, the one that called `SketchViewController` in the first place).  Once you have the calling view controller, save your image to it:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "returnToHomeViewController" {
        let homeVC = segue.destinationViewController as! AskViewController
        homeVC.sketchImage = SketchHiddenImage.image
    }
}
```