# Conditional Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

When a user taps my button, I would like to have a control flow that resembles:

```
@IBAction func confirmPurchase(sender: AnyObject) {

    if blue == true {
        let mainTabController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainTabBarController")
        self.presentViewController(mainTabController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        perform an unwind segue
    }
}
```

I am looking for method to call unwind segue in code. How is this achieved?

Comment: an unwind segue is called just like any other segue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call an *unwind segue* programmatically with `performSegueWithIdentifier`.
Instead of wiring the *unwind segue* from your button, you wire it from the `viewController` icon at the top of the view controller to the `exit` icon.

See the second part of this answer to see how it needs to be wired in the Storyboard:

[How to wire an unwind segue to be called programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992088/1630618)