# switch a normal view controller back to a tab bar view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Here is what I confused and what i want from the picture.

[See the picture, click!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsqwG.png)

The problem is, when I try using control and drag the "Add" button to the view, whatever the way it shows(show,push, etc.) it will show the third view without the tab bar, and when I click "Back" button, using the same way to connect it with the second view, it cannot show the tab button "Water".

So is there a way to show the tab bar view when click the "Back" button? and am I wrong with the setting of the third view? or I need to add code in the viewcontroller.swift?

Comment: You need to use an unwind segue.  Take a look at this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/30991551/1630618