# Trouble appending to array via segue

Tags: arrays, swift, segue

I'm trying to append to an array via segue:

```
@IBOutlet weak var addTextTextField: UITextField!    
@IBAction func addTextButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addTextSegue", sender: self)
    }    
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        let mainViewController = segue.destination as! MainViewController
        mainViewController.array.append(addTextTextField.text!)
    }
```

Its only appending to the array once, the next time I try, it overwrites the last entry. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Every segue (except an unwind segue) creates a new destination viewcontroller.  What is the control flow of your application?  Does MainViewController present this VC (the one with addTextButton) in some way?

Comment: Yes, in MainViewController I have a button that presents (segues) a second View Controller where the `addTextTextField` and the `addTextButton` is.

Comment: OK.  Use an *unwind segue* to return to the `MainViewController` like I did in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992088/1630618).

Comment: @vacawama I´m not able to control drag to the exit icon. Nothing happens when trying to control drag. The exit icon doesn't respond. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you control dragging from a button or the ViewController icon?

Comment: I have tried both from the button, and the ViewController icon.

Comment: I'm sorry, it was a Xcode bug. Needed to restart computer.

Comment: @vacawama Last question: Now the segue works, but it adds two entries to the array. If I type in "Test" in the text field, the array reads: Test, Test. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Uh, did you wire it from a button and then also call it programmatically?  You'll get 2 segues that way.

Comment: Yes, that was it... When using unwind segue, is it possible to also use a "normal" segue from another button? I would like a cancel button that takes the user back to the previous VC without adding to the array?

Comment: You should just use a second unwind segue with a different id. A regular segue will create a new VC which you don't want.