# How to pass data between different tabs in a tab bar controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, swift3

Im trying to pass an array between two VC. I understand how we are suppose to pass data forwards and backwards using segue, but for a tab bar controller you would have to pass data forwards and backwards? My storyboard flows like this Tab bar controller -> VC1/ VC2 im trying to pass data from VC1 to VC2, more specifically an array.

Comment: here's a concise example to share data across controllers using a singleton Swift class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44380145/2162226

Comment: [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47751962/3681880)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this question: [iPhone: How to Pass Data Between Several Viewcontrollers in a Tabbar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363777/iphone-how-to-pass-data-between-several-viewcontrollers-in-a-tabbar-app)

Also the imho cleanest way is to use the NSNotificationcenter. It's simple: [How to use NSNotificationcenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Comment: thanks, I knew other people would have similar problems but I couldnt find any good answers from so via google or recommendations.