# Let destination VC know current VC is delegate through UITabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set the **currentVC** as the **delegate** for the **destinationVC** that is being navigated to through a **UITabBarController** and embedded in a **UINavigationController**.

I cant set the current VC as the delegate because **prepareForSegue** never gets triggered and the other solutions provided doesn't work either (bottom code).

This was all set up as **Storyboards** with **Interface-builder**

This is the architecture:

> --> UITabBarController
>
> > -->UINavigationController
> >
> > > --> currentVC (Set this as the delegate)
> >
> > -->UINavigationController
> >
> > > --> destinationVC

This does nothing:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

   print ("The Segue was triggered")
   let destinationVC = segue.destination as! MyViewController
   destinationVC.delegate = self

}
```

I also cant get this to work (it never goes through the IF statement):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let myDestinationVC = (self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers[0] as? destinationVC {
            print ("The IF statement was triggered")
            myDestinationVC.delegate = self
        }
}
```

I have a custom class for my TabBarController, that doesn't really do anything right now - I'm not sure if I need to reference that in the code above?

Comment: How are you displaying the destinationVC?  If it's a tab on the tab bar, then the architecture you provided isn't correct as the destinationVC would not be on the UINavigationController's view stack.

Comment: You are right, I updated the architecture to reflect this. Each have their own UINavigationController. @clawesome

Comment: Are the destinationVC and currentVC on the same tab or different tabs?

Comment: Same tabbarcontroller - different “tabs” @chickenparm

Comment: Are you sure a delegate is the best solution here? What are you trying to pass between these view controllers?

Comment: @chickenparm I want to call a function that stops the loader from showing in currentVC when data is done uploading to Firebase on the destinationVC

Comment: Check out this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651507/passing-data-between-tab-viewed-controllers-in-swift

Comment: I've already tried that and I get: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController'  to 'Project.DestinationVC' @chickenparm

Comment: @Brewski That's because the controller at `self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[1]` in your case is a `UINavigationController`.  You would need to to use `if let navController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController, let destinationVC = navController.viewControllers.last as? DestinationVC { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working and tested implementation.  Not the best way to accomplish this, but will work for what you've described.

```
class MyTabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    // Replace with your sending view controller class's type
    var sendingViewController: SendingViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self

        // Iterate all view controllers to make sure they are instantiated and
        // get reference to the sendingViewController
        viewControllers?.forEach {
            if let navigationController = $0 as? UINavigationController {
                // Replace with the type of your sending view controller
                if let sendingViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? SendingViewController {
                    self.sendingViewController = sendingViewController
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

        if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController {
            // Replace with the type of your receiving view controller
            if let receivingViewController = navigationController.topViewController as? ReceivingViewController,
                let sendingViewController = sendingViewController {
                // Perform actions here
                receivingViewController.view.backgroundColor = sendingViewController.view.backgroundColor
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but can't get it to 'trigger', is there a way to include your code in my existing tabBarController code which uses tags (I tried removing mine and still could not get yours to work):  override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

Comment: Look at the method I used in this example, it uses `didSelect viewController: UIViewController`

Comment: If you still can't get the callback or 'trigger' then your delegate must be improperly set.